# Limit of infinite sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $x$ be a real number such as $0 < x < 1$, compute the following series 
$$\sum^\infty _{n=2} \frac{x^n}{n-1}$$ $$\sum^\infty _{n=2} \frac{x^n}{n+1}
$$

For instance, I made something like this : $$\frac{x^n}{n-1} = \frac{x^n}{n(1-\frac{1}{n})} \sim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^n}{n}(1+\frac{1}{n} + o(\frac{1}{n})) = \frac{x^n}{n-1} + o(\frac{1}{n})$$

and finaly we have something like this :

$$ \sum_{n=2} ^\infty \frac{x^n}{n-1} \sim \sum^\infty _{n=2}\frac{x^n}{n} = -ln(1-x)$$

However something let me think that this result couldn't be the good one.

NB : sorry for my bad english

Comment: Your method is sound, but you dropped a factor of $x$.  Check your work.

Comment: Hello $\frac{x^n}{n} * \frac{1}{n} = \frac{x^n}{n^2} \leq \frac{1}{n^2} = o(\frac{1}{n})$ So the factor that i dropped has no importance ? Am I wrong ? :)

Comment: You actually can't do a series on equivalents: For example if you take: $\frac{1}{2^n}$ and $\frac{1}{2^n}+ \frac{1}{n!}$ are equivalent, but their series are not equal, since one is equal to 2 and the other to 2+e. Equivalents can only tell you something about convergence of series, but not their value.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $n^\prime = n-1$:

$\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty = \sum\limits_{n^\prime=1}^\infty {x^{n^\prime + 1} \over n^\prime} = x \sum\limits_{n^\prime}^\infty {x^{n^\prime} \over n^\prime} = -x \ln(1-x)$.

Comment: Simple and efficient, thank you very much :)